# Check 'Profiles' created date

Tags: administration, profile, admin, system-admin

As an admin, I have been given the task to check and audit the profiles that are currently on Salesfroce.

Is there a way to see when they were created? (Created Date?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login to **Workbench** or open **Developer Console** and simply run this Query:

`SELECT Name, CreatedDate FROM Profile`

If you want to know about specific profile then use `WHERE` clause:

`SELECT Name, CreatedDate FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Profile Name'`